# Web3js unable to connect error

Tags: web3js, dapp-development

I'm quite new to etherium development, so most probably I'm doing smth wrong. I have a ganache running locally, a contract deployed there and I want to build a small app to get familiar with the process. 
I've chosen Vue for the app development and currently I ran into a problem with web3 connection to the ganache.

In my root component I create an instance of Web3:

```
const etherUri = 'http://127.0.0.1:7545'

let web3 = new Web3(Web3.currentProvider)

if (!web3.isConnected) {
    return 'Unable to connect to ethereum node at ' + etherUri
} else {
    let accounts = web3.eth.accounts
    return accounts
}
```

Ganache is up and running, Metamask connects to it without any problems. However, trying to connect from my app I always get `isConnected = false`.

The app runs as a `npm run dev` server. No errors in console.

I don't use js that much, so probably there are some mistakes in my setup. Any clues would be highly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Update with web3 logs...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it

```
window.addEventListener('load', function() {

    // Checking if Web3 has been injected by the browser (Mist/MetaMask)
    if (typeof web3 !== 'undefined') {
        // Use Mist/MetaMask's provider
        web3js = new Web3(web3.currentProvider);
    } else {
        console.log('No web3? You should consider trying MetaMask!')
        // fallback - use your fallback strategy (local node / hosted node +     in-dapp id mgmt / fail)
        web3js = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider("http://    localhost:8545"));
    }

    // Now you can start your app & access web3 freely:
    startApp()

})
```

[Web3 - Ethereum Browser Environment Check](https://github.com/MetaMask/faq/blob/master/DEVELOPERS.md#partly_sunny-web3---ethereum-browser-environment-check)

Comment: Thanks a lot, I've came to this eventually. In fact, my code works as well, despite isConnected is false I can fetch accounts and work with contracts.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using vue then try this (similar to answer by shawn):

```
const Web3 = require('web3');
let web3js;

export default {
created() {
  if (typeof web3 !== 'undefined') {
    web3js = new Web3(web3.currentProvider);
    // then call functions to determine account and balance
  } else {
    web3js = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider(provider));
    // replace provider with URL of your choice
  }
},
...
};
```

[Web3/Vue implementation on Github](https://github.com/RyanHendricks/quasar-dapp/blob/master/src/layouts/default.vue)